# How to use Single Sign-On with a node.js app on Bluemix

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I don't understand where is the problem. I followed some tutorials and the doc of SSO. I always have the same problem : my app does not start. My app and my service are well bounded.

```
cf push
```

Here is the error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2nLV.jpg)

Then when I use the cf logs :

```
cf logs sso-8
```

Picture of the response :
[Error 1/3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4gdp.jpg)

Here is my code now :

```
//package.json
{
"name": "NodejsStarterApp",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "Insert description here",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "express": "latest",
    "passport": "latest",
    "body-parser": "latest",
    "cookie-parser": "latest",
    "express-session": "latest",
    "cfenv": "1.0.x",
    "passport-idaas-openidconnect": "latest"
},
"repository": {},
"engines": {
    "node": "4.x"
} 
}


//app.js
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-idaas-openidconnect').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
   done(null, obj);
});

var services = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES || "{}");
var ssoConfig = services.SingleSignOn[0];
var client_id = ssoConfig.credentials.clientId;
var client_secret = ssoConfig.credentials.secret;
var authorization_url = ssoConfig.credentials.authorizationEndpointUrl;
var token_url = ssoConfig.credentials.tokenEndpointUrl;
var issuer_id = ssoConfig.credentials.issuerIdentifier;
var callback_url = 'https://sso-8.mybluemix.net/auth/sso/callback';

var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-idaas-openidconnect').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
        authorizationURL : authorization_url,
        tokenURL : token_url,
        clientID : client_id,
        scope: 'openid',
        response_type: 'code',
        clientSecret : client_secret,
        callbackURL : callback_url,
        skipUserProfile: true,
        issuer: issuer_id
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        done(null, profile);
    });
});

passport.use(Strategy);
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {}));

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        req.session.originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}

app.get('/auth/sso/callback', function(req, res, next) {               
    var redirect_url = req.session.originalUrl;                
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
        successRedirect: '/hello',                                
        failureRedirect: '/failure',                        
    })(req,res,next);
});

app.get('/hello', ensureAuthenticated, function(request, response) {
    request.send('Hello, '+ request.user['id'] + '!\n' + '<a href="/logout">Log Out</a>');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/failure', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Login failed');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<h1>Bluemix Service: Single Sign On</h1>' + '<p>Sign In with a Social Identity Source (SIS): Cloud directory, Facebook, Google+ or LinkedIn.</p>' + '<a href="/auth/sso/callback">Sign In with a SIS</a>');
});

var appport = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8888;
var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
var server = app.listen(appport, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The application need to be pushed to Bluemix first and be running before you can bind the SSO Service to it.

Push application to Bluemix and stage it
Then you need to create the SSO Service as Unbound,
When the SSO Service has been fully created and configured you can then bind it to the application.

Comment: Thank you Jenny. The documentation of the SSO Service mentions the following steps in this order :
1. Create the app and the service
2. Bind them
3. Modify the app
4. Push the app

This is what I did and the app did not start. However, I found where my mistake came from! Actually, the version of the module :
      "passport-idaas-openidconnect": "latest"
should not be "latest" but "2.0.0".

I changed it and now it works. Thanks again though :)